# Tool for measuring HTML text transfer time?

Tags: html, performance, response, transfer

The HTML of a web page is basically a text document. Are there any tools that can analyze the transfer time of the text itself?

I have a page that is taking ~2s to transfer once the transfer has begun, I'm trying to figure out at what points in the output it's slowing down or hiccuping.

For example, let's say you were controlling the text output thusly:

> echo "Begin"

> Sleep 2 seconds

> echo "End"

I would want the tool to show that there was a 2 second pause between "Begin" and "End". Anything like this exist?

Comment: is your HTML  static text or generated by a script language like php , ruby ,python or other ?

Comment: Irrelevant. I just want to know how fast the text transfers over the network and where the delays are.

Comment: if you use Windows  try this command:   tracert  <yoursiteaddress>   .  if you use Linux  install  `traceroute`

Comment: Well, if the hiccups are caused by the script generating it, that'll be very different (and likely much easier) to diagnose. It's also much more likely to be a problem than the network connection randomly slowing down in the middle; and if it is the network connection, you want to use a different tool, such as `iperf`, rather than using the existing webpage

Answer (score 1):

I think simulation of slow web browser could help. Open up the Developer Tools `(Menu –> More Tools –> Developer Tools or keyboard shortcut Ctrl + Shift + I on` Windows and Command + Option + I for Mac)` and select the Network tab.

Click the dropdown that says Online. From here you can pick from a few different options such as Slow 3G or Offline.

For sure `having` slow internet connection will be easier to test.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

some web browsers do have a toolbar built in, that shows transfer times for each element. (Mozilla Firefox, Google Chrome -> F12, network)

if you have GNU/Linux or BSD you can use "wget". it shows the transfer time of each resource, even if you use "--spider" and "--recursive"

or simply "time curl .." which does pretty much the same

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you would use the browser's developer tools to check timing between first and last byte.

However, you're looking to measure performance between individual chunks.  Short of making your own tool, the closest you can get is to use something like Wireshark.

In Wireshark, you can filter by TCP connection.  This isn't quite the same as filtering by HTTP requests, particularly for HTTP/2, etc.  But, it's close.

1. Start a capture on the appropriate network interface.
2. Make your HTTP request.
3. Stop the capture.
4. Enter `http` in to the filter bar.
5. Find the HTTP request you want, right click, and filter for its TCP connection.
6. Statistics -> TCP Stream Graphs -> Throughput

You'll end up with a nice graph like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

You just need to enter the URL. It will give you performance both for web and mobile, and it will tell you what you can change to optimize the performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested purely in the network transfer speed and delays, don't use an existing webpage on a webserver with all the confounding factors; instead, use a tool like `iperf` to check the speed of the connection between the two ends

That will report the network transfer speed and delays separately from any compounding factors on the server or client ends

Answer (score -1):

You can use the MutationObserver to measure changes in HTML.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

You have many examples on the Internet of how to do that including the link I sent.

Comment: This would be more suited to measuring the rendering of the DOM, I'm interested purely in the network transfer speed & delays of the text contents of the HTML document